# Concise notation for assigning `unique_ptr`?

Tags: c++11, polymorphism, unique-ptr

I have a pointer to a parent class and I want to assign a new child object to that pointer conditionally. Right now, the syntax I have is rather lengthly:

```
std::unique_ptr<ParentClass> parentPtr;
if (...) {  
  parentPtr = std::unique_ptr<ParentClass>(new ChildClass1());  
} else {
  parentPtr = std::unique_ptr<ParentClass>(new ChildClass2());  
}
```

Is there a good way of making this more readable / less lengthly?

Comment: Not really. Pointers to derived classes have no natural "common type". You can say `parentPtr.reset(new ChildClass1);`, though, which is shorter.

Comment: OK, I wrote something down to that effect. By the way, "parent"/"child" is a really inappropriate metaphor for public class inheritance. A public derived class *is* semantically like its base, i.e. it has all of its base's public properties. This is completely different from how children relate to their parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the "obvious" solution `C ? new X : new Y` does not work, since even if `X` and `Y` have a common base class `A`, the types `X *` and `Y *` have no common type. This is actually not so surprising after all if you consider that a class can have many bases (direct or indirect) and a given type may appear as a base multiple times.

You could make the conditional operator work by inserting a cast:

```
A * = C ? static_cast<A *>(new X) : static_cast<A *>(new Y);
```

But this would quickly get long and tedious to read when you try to apply this to your real situation.

However, as for `std::unique_ptr`, it offers the `reset` function which can be used to good effect here:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> p;

if (C)
{
    p.reset(new X);
}
else
{
    p.reset(new Y);
}
```

Now even if the actual `new` expressions are long, this is still nicely readable.

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities would be:

```
std::unique_ptr<ParentClass> parentPtr(condition ? 
    (ParentClass*)new ChildClass1() : 
    (ParentClass*)new ChildClass2());
```

If condition is complicated, just assign a boolean to it and then write the construction. This solution only works for a binary condition though.

Another is to embrace C++14, and use

```
parentPtr = std::make_unique<ChildClass>();
```

Comment: @TamásSzelei I'm not sure I understand? The question asks how to make the assignment less lengthy, and using make_unique indeed works for that.

Comment: @TamásSzelei time to delete all these obsolete comments, but the form of the make_unique is correct.

Comment: @Svalorzen There is no `ChildClass`, only `ChildClass1` and `ChildClass2` and the question was how to express choosing between the two instantiations in a concise way (and the first part of your answer answers that).

Comment: @TamásSzelei alas, I've already deleted my comment for you, making yours seem clueless :-)

Comment: @TamásSzelei The question is "How to make this more readable/less lengthy?" which make_unique does begin shorter than a new unique_ptr instantiation. The fact that ChildClass does not exist is because it is an example; if you think code should be copy-pastable and not just exhibit a point then I disagree with your opinion.

Comment: @Svalorzen that is not exactly my opinion either. I meant that the question is not simply about assigning the unique_ptr, but the conditional assignment; which is what the first part answers correctly, while the second part of the answer makes it seem like it was only about the assignment, and it's kind of confusing as it stands with a class name not mentioned previously. Anyway, I removed my downvote, because it was originally cast due to the now-corrected mistake.

Comment: @TamásSzelei To me the question is about a generic piece of code which the OP desires to shorten by whatever means necessary. Just like Kerrek's anwer suggests the use of reset, I suggest the use of make_unique. I don't see anything in the question asking for help solely regarding the if clause.